# Does redhat have any jdk configuration tools?

Tags: redhat, java

Red Hat seems like a very inconvenient environment for java.

On other distributions like debian and gentoo there have been system wide config tool for many years.

On red hat there's seems to be nothing available in the standard repositories and the installer for the oracle jdk doesn't write symlinks or replace the PATH entries, it seems to merely unzip.

Maybe I'm ignorant as I haven't shelled out 5k for a certification course.

Comment: Have you used the rpm version of Oracle JDK?

Comment: yes I used yum install on the extracted rpm, but I still had to do a few manual steps. no JAVA_HOME and what not. running a jboss startup didn't work, the rpm installer broke that . I found htis related question though which describes a command which is supposed to automate some things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701100/problem-changing-java-version-using-alternatives